# Android AlertDialog Issue with ImageView

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am making one custom alertdialog having ONE image. The problems I am facing are as follows:

1) For devices with small screen this alertdialog box appears to be too big. the aletdialog buttons are going out of screen( positive and negative buttons).

2) The alertdialog is getting drawn twice. ie there are 2 alertdialogs one over the other and i have to click the positive button twice to close both of them.

Here is the code for alertdialog:-

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Activity.this);
            alertdialog.setTitle("Title ");
            alertdialog.setMessage("The MEssage ");


            LayoutInflater layoutinf= LayoutInflater.from(Activity.this);
            final View view = layoutinf.inflate(R.layout.layoutfile, null);
            alertdialog.setView(view);
            alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Button1",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            //do something 
                        }
                    });
    alertdialog.show();
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

thanks

Comment: Details you provided isn't helpful for us to identify your issue

Comment: Hi Pragnani,   
For Question 1, the alertdialog box positive and negative buttons are going beyond the screen for small screen devices. Is there any property that we can set to make sure the complete alertdialog(including image and buttons) will come fully without getting cropped.

Comment: Don't set the fixed height and width for your view and its children in the xml.

Comment: If your view is complex then use this                           FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
 fl.addView(myView, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2nd question alert dialog should be like this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertdialog.setTitle("Title");
alertdialog.setPositiveButton("OK", okListener); 
alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", cancelListener); 
AlertDialog alertdialogDlg = alertdialog.create(); 
alertdialogDlg.show(); 

 public DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener = new      
 DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do something
        }
    };
```